# Remove multiple values from a field with comma delimited values - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make some changes to a specific field (Oracle DB)

I would like to know what is the best way to remove multiple values from a field with comma delimited values (string) ? 
Example:
Before: TYP,CRT,REW,PBR,ORT
Remove TYP, CRT and ORT
After: REW,PBR

Is using a nested REPLACE the only option ?

Comment: That depends; regular expressions might be a viable alternative. You should add some example data - what you've currently got in your table and what you want afterwards. Of course, the most sensible action would be to move the data from the comma delimited list into a separate details table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions162.htm#SQLRF06302):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn =
  TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(myColumn, '(TYP|CRT|ORT)(,|$)'))
```

The regex looks for TYP, CRT, or ORT followed by a comma or the end of the string. If it gets the very last value (for example the `ORT` in `REW,ORT`) it will leave a trailing comma. Rather than overcomplicate the regex, this example removes any trailing commas using the TRIM() function.

There's a SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f715/2).

Finally, Frank Schmitt's comment above is spot on - a comma-separated list like this in a column often means poor design. If you can split these values into a related details table you'll probably make things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ed. Much appreciated. I agree with you and Frank that the way the data is stored (common delimited) is not the best.  But at this point, I'm not allowed to make any changes to the database.

Comment: Glad it worked! I know that sometimes you have to take the database as it is; I've been there.

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE works only on MySQL 8+. Is there a equivalent function for REGEXP_REPLACE function?

Comment: Sorry @Ranjan but I don't know. The original question was for Oracle, which has had `REGEXP_REPLACE` for a long time now. I'd suggest posting a question with the data you have and the output/results you want. In general I think any parsing of comma-delimited strings before MySQL 8 will end up as a stored function. It's important to note that you can tear apart comma-delimited lists if you write enough code, but you can never optimize the query. It won't scale, period. If this will be a problem then consider redesigning your database.